# Let X be Topological Space ; $A\subset X$ Suppose that for each $x\in A$ there is open set U contain x such that $U\subset A$.Show that A is open in X

Tags: general-topology

Please check my proof

Since $X$ is topological space,All of collection of intersection and union of closed set is closed and open if it's open

Consider $U\subset A$ and $A\subset X$

Since $U\subset A$ ,$A\subset X$

$U\subset X$

Since U is open and it is one of intersection or union of collection of $X$,then all other set collection must be open

because $A\subset X$ then A is open

Comment: Is U open in $A$ or open in $X$? Remember, $U$ can be open in $X$ without being open in $A$.

Comment: In your answer no $x\in A$ is present, this in contrast with your question.

Comment: If we use $int(A)$ to mean the set of all interior points of $A$, then your question is trying to show that if $A\subset int(A)$ then $A$ is open. This follows from the result which says "$A$ is open iff $A=int(A)$."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For each $x \in A$ there is an open set $U_x$ such that $x \in U_x \subseteq A$.

Then we have $A= \bigcup_{x \in A}U_x$.

Hence, $A$ is a union of open sets and therefore open.

Answer (score 1):

For each $x\in A$ we define
$$\mathcal{C}_x := \{\mathcal{O}\in\tau : x\in\mathcal{O}\subseteq A\}.$$
We note that $\mathcal{C}_x\subseteq\tau$ for each $x\in A$, then, because every topology is closed under arbitrary unions, we have that $\bigcup\mathcal{C}_x\in\tau$ for all $x\in A$, which implies that
$$\left\{\bigcup\mathcal{C}_x : x\in A\right\}\subseteq\tau,$$
so, because every topology is closed under arbitrary unions,
$$\bigcup\left\{\bigcup\mathcal{C}_x : x\in A\right\}=\bigcup_{x\in A}\bigcup\mathcal{C}_x$$
is an open set. Furthermore,
$$A=\bigcup_{x\in A}\bigcup\mathcal{C}_x.$$
We prove it by doble contention, let's go with the first. Suppose $w\in A$, then, by the hypothesis, exists an open set $\mathcal{O}$ such that $w\in\mathcal{O}\subseteq A$, which implies that $\mathcal{O}\in\mathcal{C}_w$ and, since $w\in\mathcal{O}$, we have that $w\in\bigcup\mathcal{C}_w$, which implies, because $w\in A$, that
$$w\in\bigcup_{x\in A}\bigcup\mathcal{C}.$$
Therefore we have the first contention, the second is simple. So
$$A=\bigcup_{x\in A}\bigcup\mathcal{C}_x,$$
hence $A$ is open.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement " Since X is topological space,All of collection of intersection and union of closed set is closed and open if it's open" is not valid.

An arbitrary intersection of open sets might not be open and an arbitrary union of closed sets might not be closed.

Your proof needs improvement due the fact that just $ U\subset A$ does not make $A$ an open set.

A very good proof is provided by Fred so you can enjoy it and think about improving your own proof.