# Showing open set

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space; let $A$ be a subset of $X$. Suppose that for each $x \in A$ there is an open set $U$ containing $x$ such that $U \subset A$. Show that $A$ is open in $X$.

I was given the following definition: A subset $U$ of $X$ is said to be open in $X$ if for each $x \in U$ there is a basis element $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B$ and $B \subset U$.

So I did:

Let $x \in A$. By hypothesis there is an open set $U$ containing $x$ such that $U \subset A$. So since $U$ is open it follows that there is a basis element $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B$ and $B \subset U \subset A$. So $A$ is open in $X$.

Could someone let me know what I did wrong? The solution in my book is the same as the answer provided here:

[Let X be Topological Space ; $A\subset X$ Suppose that for each $x\in A$ there is open set U contain x such that $U\subset A$.Show that A is open in X](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2174171/let-x-be-topological-space-a-subset-x-suppose-that-for-each-x-in-a-there-i)

Comment: Hm. Your proof looks essentially okay, although it looks like you haven't actually defined your basis $\mathcal{B}$ (to be fair, $\mathcal{B}$  is also never defined in your statement of the definition of an open set). Given your definition of an open set, the easiest correction might be to define $\mathcal{B} = \mathcal{T}$, where $\mathcal{T}$ is the topology on $X$.

Comment: @mheldman oh yes sorry. By $\mathcal{B}$ I meant a basis for the topology $X$. I’ll add your correction to my answer then. Would you be willing to compare/contrast my answer to the answer in the link I posted? I’ve been googling this question and all answers are essentially the same as the answer in that link. Why do they reach the conclusion that $A$ is a union of open sets?

Comment: Yeah, I assumed you meant that. I think your answer is okay, but the easiest thing would just be to note that $\mathcal{T}$ is a basis for the topology, and since every $x\in A$ is contained in some $U\in \mathcal{T}$ where $U\subseteq A$, $A$ is open. It's fine to pick an arbitrary basis (as long as you prove that a basis always exists), but it's usually better to pick a specific basis.

Comment: To address your confusion about the other answers, another way to show a set is open is to show that it is a union of open sets (as per the definition of a topology). If you haven't proven that $\mathcal{T}$ is a basis for itself (which is straightforward, but adds a few extra lines), then you can avoid doing that by taking this route. Both methods are valid though.

Comment: @mheldmam I see! Thank you so much this clarified a lot!

Comment: I think for a topological space $X$ it is wrong to "define" a set $U$ to be open if for each $x\in U$ there is a basis element $B\in\mathcal B$ such that $x\in B\subseteq U$. You can only speak of a topological space $X$ if a topology $\tau_X\subseteq\wp(X)$ is defined. Then a set $U$ is by definition open if $U\in\tau_X$. In short: to define a set to be open a basis should not be needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are given a set $X$ and a collection of subsets $\mathcal{B}$ of $X$ satisfying certain properties.

You can then *define* a topology $\mathcal{T}(\mathcal{B})$ on $X$ by

> $O \subseteq X$ is open (i.e. $O \in \mathcal{T}(\mathcal{B})$) iff $\forall x \in O: \exists B_x \in \mathcal{B}: x \in B_x \subseteq O$

which can be shown to be a topology (i.e. obeying the 3 axioms) because $\mathcal{B}$ was not arbitrary but obeyed the special properties.

Now we want to show the simple fact that

> $O \in \mathcal{T}(\mathcal{B})$ iff $\forall x \in O: \exists O_x \in \mathcal{T}(\mathcal{B}): x \in O_x \subseteq O$.

The left to right implication is very trivial: for every $x$ we pick $O_x = O$.

The right to left implication is also easy: the right hand side condition implies that $O = \bigcup \{O_x: x \in O\}$ (all $O_x$ are subsets of $O$, hence so is their union, which shows $\supseteq$; and every $x$ is in its own $O_x$ which shows $\subseteq$) and so $O$ is a union of elements of $\mathcal{T}(\mathcal{B})$ and so in $\mathcal{T}(\mathcal{B})$ itself, as topologies are closed under unions.

Note that this proof only needs that $\mathcal{T}(\mathcal{B})$ is a topology, *not* how it was defined from the collection $\mathcal{B}$. I assume that this has been checked prior to this.